# Achieve 50/50 Background in CSS without overlap

Tags: html, css

I attempted to create a div with two background images: one on the top half and one on the bottom like so:

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPm8L.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezu9z.png)

However, on trying to achieve this, the images overlapped and weren't positioned in the right place.

Is there a way to achieve the output desired.

N.B. There are similar questions to this but none are exactly the same as what I am describing, so please don't reply with "duplicate question". Thank you

HTML:

```
<<Content etc....>>

</div>
```

CSS:

.grid {

```
    background-image: 
        url('/assets/img/stripes.svg'),
        url('/assets/img/checks.svg')
        ;
    background-position:
        top,
        bottom;
    background-repeat:
    no-repeat,
    no-repeat;
```

}

Tried a 50% background on both top and bottom, got an overlapping pattern

Comment: You want those specific background patterns?

Comment: No can be any picture

Comment: This won't work as the chance your image's aspect ratio is exactly half the bounding box is close to zero, and since backgrounds stack on top of each other. You could try with `background-size: 100% 50%;`, but that would ignore aspect ratio. You will have to make two elements for this, though you could get away with a `:before` and `:after` in this case?

Comment: How would you manage using a :before and :after ?

Answer (score 1):

Using `background-size: 100% 50%` I can achieve your goal.

```css
div {
    background-image: 
        url('https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.a220b8b3e599ae7afbfc806b12a8a60a?rik=WJ85w9n3r%2bqP%2fw&pid=ImgRaw&r=0'),
        url('https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.ca2656b3353b4371231986102d036beb?rik=6Hisid9W5tT%2fJA&riu=http%3a%2f%2f4.bp.blogspot.com%2f-FINHU-YJ8aU%2fTsPlBH1giNI%2fAAAAAAAACvQ%2fhjGwN7CDfao%2fs1600%2fbackgrounds-high-resolution-1280x1024-wallpaper-hd-tree-bridge.jpg&ehk=qQNCbbrfnZlctiC9qS%2bQ7sEmhE8UDXssJv3s8pcBDMs%3d&risl=&pid=ImgRaw&r=0')
        ;
    background-position:
        top,
        bottom;
    background-repeat:
    no-repeat,
    no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately - I would like the two backgrounds to stretch across the entire width of the div - I have described the problem in this new thread ---> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77037350/set-up-div-with-content-over-split-50-background-with-two-different-images

Comment: @BeginnerCoder1992 it is a background over the entirety of the div. I have set the div to be of a width of 200px for the example, but you can set it to 100% and then the div will occupy the entire width of its parent. The background occupies the entirety of the width of the div, but the div's width is limited in our example. So it's not the background that was limited.